# JDBC ODBC MS Access 2003 Update query does not update register

Tags: java, sql, ms-access, jdbc-odbc

Using Ms Access 2003 on Windows Vista
Java 1.7.0_45 & NetBeans IDE 7.4

I'm trying to run a simple UPDATE Query on a table named EMPLOYEES

```
stmt.executeUpdate("UPDATE EMPLOYEES SET Name='John' WHERE Code='A07'");
```

But the name of the employee with Code A07 does not change in the database.

Other queries (INSERT, SELECT) are working fine, for example:

```
 stmt.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO EMPLOYEES VALUES (....)");
```

or

```
 ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM " + nombreTabla);
```

work as expected.

For the UPDATE, I have tried different things, but none of them working:

- Using executeQuery instead of executeUpdate for an UPDATE query raises SQL Exception: "No ResultSet was produced"
- Adding "[ ]" to the fields did not update the record either:

  stmt.executeUpdate("UPDATE EMPLEADOS SET [Name]='John' WHERE [Code]='A07'");

I've never worked with Access before, I don't know what I'm doing wrong. Could be a privilege problem? How could I grant the update privilege in that case?

Comment: do this__ int i = stmt.executeUpdate("UPDATE EMPLOYEES SET Name='John' WHERE Code='A07'"); ___and check whether the variable i is greater than zero or not. If it is not zero that means your update should occur.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, it returns i=1, but when I check the table in MS Access, the name does not change (I did refresh and even reopen the database).

Comment: try stmt.close() after updating .

Comment: the Statement stmt was created in an try-with-resources. But I've tried to release it with stmt.close() and the record does not change either.

Comment: then i think you should create another database with diff name

Comment: After executing your UPDATE statement try explicitly invoking the `.Close()` method of your `Connection` object.

Comment: thanks, tt works doing a commit() of the conexión after the update

Answer (score 0):

Problems with updates not being written back to the Access database are often found to be the result of not explicitly closing the database `Connection` object by invoking its `.Close()` method. Under JDBC-ODBC if the connection object simply goes out of scope while the connection is still `.Open()` then the pending updates are sometimes discarded.